# GCD & c++ memory issues

Tags: ios

When running this code

```
 for ( int i=0; i<4; i++) {

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0,0), ^{
        std::vector<unsigned char> d(1000*1000*4);
        printf("D\n");
    });
}
```

the memory grows without being released.

for example after running the above code, the memory was at 32mb after all 4 blocks have been executed.

when commenting out the line with std::vector the end memory was 23mb.

Will be happy to understand why this is happens and how to release the memory.

Thanks

Comment: Where is that code defined?

Comment: i've tested it inside viewDidLoad and also in the camera output frame delegate